# Alexa slot value issue

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Let me give a background of my issue.

I have a custom slot type **YesNo**. It handles *yes* *no* and it's synonyms. I am using NodeJs for my handlers.

I have an OfferIntent where I am using this slot. I have made this slot a mandatory one and I am handling the prompts in my code. Code always asks a yes or no question like "Blah blah blah and Are you interested in applying for this offer?".

I have set up User Utterances for this slot like,

```
{confirmation} please
{confirmation} I am
{confirmation}
```

Problem is when I addElicitSlotDirective for this slot from another intent, and if I answer just "yes" it's not going forward. Device log shows "yes" as the value Alexa captured but still it re-prompts. When I answer with "yes I am" or "Yes Please" it works as expected.

```
 return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .addElicitSlotDirective("confirmation", {
            name: "OfferIntent",
            confirmationStatus: "NONE",
            slots: {}
          })
          .speak(speechText + speechText1)
          .reprompt(speechText1)
          .getResponse();
```

If I access this intent directly instead of redirect using addElicitSlotDirective, "yes" works fine.

I compared the Device Logs for both the cases and found no difference except the time and requestID.

Please let me know if you need any additional info. I think it's an issue with Alexa. Please share your thoughts.